# Laravel рассылка писем в очереди

Tags: laravel, email

Суть вопроса : как реализовать отправку писем в приложении написанном на Laravel в очереди так чтоб отправитель не ждал пока foreach пройдет по всем email из массива.

Реализовано в данный момент так:

```html
$emailList = ['mail@mail.com', 'mail1@mail.com', 'mail2@mail.com', ... ,'mailN@mail.com' ]
$template = 'emails.template';
$data = [
            'template'  => $template,
            'text'      => $data->body,
            'subject'   => $data->subject,
        ];

foreach ($emailList as $email){
            $sending = Mail::queue($data['template'], ['data' => $data['text']], function($message) use               ($data,$email)
            {
                $message->to($email, 'Дорогой клиент')
                    ->subject($data['subject']);
            });
}
```

К сожалению нужно в итоге получить отдельное письмо адресованное каждому пользователю, поэтому запихнуть массив в $message->сс или $message->bcc - неприемлемо, а сконкатенировать несколько  $message->to не выходит.
При такой реализации пользователь ждет все то время пока foreach всех перебирает. При 100 email не особо страшно но когда их становится 2, 3 ,4... сотни станет уже грустно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, варианты решения этой ситуации.

При попытке сделать так:

```html
$sending = Mail::queue($data['template'], ['data' => $data['text']], function($message) use ($emailList)
        {
            foreach ($emailList as $email) {
                $message->to($email);
            }
                $message->subject('test');
        });
```

Т.е. foreach передает значения исключительно в получателя, Mail::failures() пустой, но при такой реализации приходит одно письмо на несколько адресов, мне же нужно отдельное письмо каждому получателю.

Comment: а отдельную задачу создать нельзя? в которой уже будет перебираться цикл.

Comment: можно, но всё упирается в то что при переборке на каждый адрес должно уйти письмо, а это плюс ко времени обработки. Да и с такой реализацией не особо похоже на реализацию очередью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решается [событиями](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events) или [задачами с использованием очередей](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues).

Кнфигурируем:

QUEUE_DRIVER=redis или QUEUE_DRIVER=database в env файле.

Если database то делаем:

php artisan queue:table

php artisan migrate

Далее в консоли:

php artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3  --tries=3

или

php artisan queue:work database --sleep=3  --tries=3

Это будет работать пока вы не остановите нажатием ctrl + c

Для БД не рекомендуется запускать более одного слушателя очереди. Т.к. возможны ошибки с блокировками таблиц.

Инструкция для запуска слушателя очереди под супервизором присутствует по ссылке.

Соответственно выглядеть это будет так

```
foreach ($emailList as $email) dispatch(new SendEmail($email));
```

И класс задачи:

php artisan make:job SendEmail

```
namespace App\Jobs;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $email;
    /**
    * Create a new job instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
    * Execute the job.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function handle()
    {   
        // send email here
    }
}
```

Можно еще создать таблицу для неудавшихся задач:

php artisan queue:failed-table

php artisan migrate

Они будут доступны к перезапуску в дальнейшем.

В общем, по ссылкам на достаточно простом английском объяснено все тоже самое только подробней.

PS:
Либо, использовать [кнокретно преднозначенный для этого механизм](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#queueing-mail):

```
Mail::to($request->user())
     ->cc($moreUsers)
     ->bcc($evenMoreUsers)
     ->queue(new OrderShipped($order));
```

Что, впрочем, не избавляет нас от необходимости настройки очереди и запуска слушателя очереди.

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал через задачи, слушатель очереди (queue:listen --timeout=900) в планировщике как крон запускаю. Всё вроде бы ок, но при тесте на ~120 адресов, по завершению прохода циклом по массиву адресов, значение поля attempts делает +1 и начинается еще один проход по массиву, затем еще один... Избавился этим проверкой попытки в методе handle задачи` if ($this->attempts() < 2) {
            foreach ($this->email as $email) {
                //отправка сообщения
            }
        }` Подскажите, как можно реализовать корректную проверку завершения задачи

Comment: Как вариант попробовал foreach обрабатывать адреса в методе контроллера ( репозитория) и каждое письмо уходит отдельной задачей. Так всё получилось, но насколько такая реализация правильна?

Comment: Такая реализация более правильная. В первом случае возможно слушатель пытается запустить задачу в то время как она отрабатывает. Т.е. допустим слушатель опрашивает задачу раз в секунду, а выполняется она десять секунд. Возможно это происходит из за запуска по крону. Самый лучший вариант все таки запускаться под супервизором. И перенастроить на использование redis.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант настроить [Gearman](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.gearman.php) или [RabbitMq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).
Gearman - Базовые клиент и обработчик Gearman, отправка задач.

Суть в том что у вас есть сервер очереди есть скрипт, которому нужны результаты работы функции, шлёт на сервер название функции и аргументы, а на сервере зарегистрирован воркер ему передаются данные для обработки и имя функции.Если воркер для такой функции не зарегистрирован, то он становится в очередь. Для корректной работы Gearman обычно используется с Supervisor (система  для контроля подключённых процессов).

Comment: Безусловно вариант, но я все же надеюсь найти способ реализовать эту задачу тем что есть. Вроде бы и очереди есть и swiftmailer стабильный инструмент, но вот реализовать свою задумку не получалось. Единственное приблеженное к решению было в получателе указывать статичный адрес, а остальные указывать как копию, но на стороне получателя будет выглядеть не так как должно.

Comment: можете использовать очередь на php

Comment: или/и фоновый режим

Comment: Про фоновый режим не совсем понял, можно поподробнее.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/132609/ вот на хабре есть.